# Formatting a story collection for submission to publishers

Tags: formatting, short-story

Anyone know of a definitive online resource on formatting a story collection for submission to publishers and agents? One knotty question in particular: does one use the title of the book throughout the manuscript in the page headers or does the header change with each story to reflect the name of that story? Oddly, I can't find anything on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every publisher is different.  If you use an agent they may have their own quirks.

Find out what the place  you are sending it to wants in the way of formatting.
And yes, you may have to (re)format it for every target  you send the mss to.

Comment: Indeed. If the publisher you're sending the material to realizes you haven't spent some extra effort on communication to them alone, you get minus points...

Answer (score 0):

William Shunn's [Proper Manuscript Format](https://www.shunn.net/format/2009/03/story_collection_format.html) website recommends that authors use the same formatting you would use with a novel manuscript. The page header should contain the standard Name, Book Title, and Page#. Also, "start each story on its own page with the title centered halfway down the page."